# How to exclude a category in the following Code?

Tags: exclude

I give out the Name of the category (in single post) with the following code:

```
 foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
   echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
 }
```

If my postings ist in two categories and I want generally one of this both to exclude (its name is comments)...how to proceed ?

At the moment he gives out both categorie..."comments" and the second category, where my post is in.

I tried this here, but it doesnt function:

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    if (!in_array($category->cat_name,array('cat1_to_exclude','cat2_to_exclude','cat3_to_exclude')) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Try following ...  `if( ! in_category( array( 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3') ) ) { do stuff }`

Comment: This is basic PHP and doesn't really belong to our site.